# Trying to automate downloading campaign disclosure reports from an ASP server but it uses an encrypted __VIEWSTATE to handle important data

Tags: python, asp.net, viewstate

In my line of work, I often need to look at campaign disclosure reports for my state from ethics.ga.gov. However, the state system is one of the shittiest webapps I've ever dealt with.

It only provides contribution data per report. There are six reports per election cycle. And to add insult to injury, the system is slow. Not only are you having to download a shit ton of files, you have to wait a good minute for the damn thing to generate.

This is like an obvious opportunity to automate the process. What I had planned on doing is writing a program where I can input a URL of the page that links to all disclosure reports, and it will download all the contribution reports.

For a given candidate, I would input a link to this page - http://media.ethics.ga.gov/Search/Campaign/Campaign_Name.aspx?NameID=5753&FilerID=C2009000086&Type=candidate (the view report links are in the dropdown list titled "campaign contribution reports"). I then plan on following each of those links to the report page, following that link to the contributions page, and downloading the csv file. Once I have the csv file, (I think) the project comes under the scope of my coding ability.

The problem I am stuck on right now is that I can't figure out how to follow the view report links. The system is written in ASP. The links call a javascript postback function with a call of the sort "View Report". ctl02 is the identifier of the control. It appears that the information to map that control identifier to the url I need (in this case http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Campaign/Campaign_ReportOptions.aspx?NameID=5753&FilerID=C2009000086&CDRID=85776) is embedded in an encrypted __VIEWSTATE field.

I installed the Firebug debugger to try and get data that way. While I am very new to Firebug, all I could find is that in the net tab it shows a GET request to the URL that I need.

Obviously, somehow my browser is getting the next page, which means it should be automatable, but I am now at a loss. I've been working this up in python because I'm really starting to like it, but everything's negotiable. I am doing this on a mac (with full gnu environment), and would prefer to keep working in the environment I am familiar with, but I do have a windows xp vm with visual c++ '10 if I have to go that route.

What do y'all think?

Comment: I can't seem to find a "campaign contribution reports" which links to a page with "View Report" in it.

Comment: Oops. A link copied as plain text.  Edited to add link to Campaign Contribution Reports page.

Comment: Ugh. That's nasty. Have you tried contacting the website operator to see if they can provide an alternate means of accessing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the data wasn't in the encrypted __VIEWSTATE at all.  There was a POST operation that Firebug was clearing on a redirect (despite having it set not to clear things.)  I ran it with the Chrome dev console, and I was able to capture the POST data and replicate the POST operation in my application.  That got me the URL I was looking for.

Thanks to everyone that looked at this!